# Is the derivative function a group homomorphism on $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be the set of real-valued, differentiable functions (the operation on $G$ is addition). Is the derivative function $D$ a group homomorphism from $G\rightarrow G$?

---

I'm pretty sure it is. Let $f,g\in G$, then

$\hspace{150pt} D(f+g)=D(f)+D(g)$

I can't think of any functions where the condition isn't satisfied, but I figured I'd ask around just to be sure.

Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that $D(f + g) = Df + Dg$.  However, if you're asking if differentiation is a group homomorphism from $G$ to $G$, the answer is no.

Look for any function that is once, but not twice differentiable.

Comment: What kind of function on $G$ wouldn't be twice differentiable?

Comment: Nevermind.... I SEE lol.

Answer (score 1):

This is a property of the derivative. Wiki gives a proof http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_differentiation

Comment: I thought so. Thanks!